# Hooking function using minhook. C++

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, reverse-engineering

I have the following code:
in it, I'm trying to hook the game function I need.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <MinHook.h>

uintptr_t base = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
uintptr_t GameAssembly = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(L"GameAssembly.dll");
uintptr_t SetOffset = 0x341C20;

void CreateConsole()
{
    AllocConsole();
    FILE* f;
    freopen_s(&f, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
}

void init()
{
    MH_Initialize();
    CreateConsole();
    printf("started");
}

bool(__fastcall* build)(DWORD*, DWORD*, DWORD*);
bool __stdcall build_hook(DWORD* __this, DWORD* buildingDef, DWORD* methodinfo)
{
    printf("buildingDef is called!!!");
    return true;
}

void main()
{
    init();
    MH_CreateHook(reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(GameAssembly + SetOffset), &build_hook, (LPVOID*)&build);
    MH_EnableHook(reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(GameAssembly + SetOffset));
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)main, 0, 0, 0);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

This is what this function looks like in dumper:

```
    {
      "Address": 3415072,
      "Name": "Game.Managers.BuildingManager.BuildingManager$$RequestStartBuilding",
      "Signature": "bool Game_Managers_BuildingManager_BuildingManager__RequestStartBuilding (Game_Managers_BuildingManager_BuildingManager_o* __this, Game_Managers_BuildingManager_BuildingConfiguration_BuildingDef_o* buildingDef, const MethodInfo* method);",
      "TypeSignature": "iiii"
    }
```

My code successfully reaches "printf("buildingDef is called!!!");", and after that the game crashes(see screenshot).
What did I do wrong when using minhook?

I tried to change the return value of the true function to false, but the game crashed anyway

Comment: A) what is "dumper"?, B) where is screenshot?, C) you should call the original function in the hook.

Comment: Any update? Your problem needs to be improved so that the community can handle it.